# PHP page is delivering the same result regardless of IF condition

Tags: php

I am trying to view a PHP page with and without using an iframe, but the result is the same regardless of the IF condition using $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST'] to detect that it is in an iframe.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST']) and $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST'] == 'iframe') {
// do something
}
```

The result is always true until I manually refresh the page that isn't using the iframe.  Any suggestions to make this work?  Seems like some kind of buffer issue, but I have not been able to solve it with flush().

Comment: What do you mean by "view", as it related to server-side code and iframe?

Comment: View from a browser like Chrome, edge, firefox, etc.2 tabs open using a different method to display the php page and getting the same result, even though it should be a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a header to revalidate solved my problem.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
```